# Jacoco Exclude Packages Not Reducing Total Lines to Cover

Tags: maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I'm trying to exclude some packages from the Jacoco coverage scan, but it's not working like how I would expect. Here's my Maven POM configuration for Jacoco:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/pojo/**/*</exclude>
        </excludes>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

The behavior I'm experiencing is that the files are being set to 0% lines covered instead of reducing the total lines to cover, which is actually reducing my coverage percentage. So how do I correct this?

EDIT: A workaround for this issue is to remove the file entirely from SonarQube using sonar properties:

```
<sonar.exclusions>**/pojo/**/*</sonar.exclusions>
```

However, this is just a workaround since now I can't see code smells from those files (there probably aren't any since they are POJOs, but I like the sense of security of knowing for a fact there are no code smells).

Comment: where is your <execution><id>...</id><goals><goal>...</goal></goals></execution> ?

Comment: Current explanation of your case is not different from existing answered questions about this - e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50294239/244993 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/39446033/244993 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/28147991/244993 If it is different, then please make sure to add more details. And please make sure to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to provide enough details, including Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 1):

Total lines of code in Sonar are not totally managed by Jacoco. You need to add this property to your `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
    <sonar.coverage.exclusions>**/pojo/**/*</sonar.coverage.exclusions>
</properties>
```